# Rails 3: "undefined local variable or method" if I put content in a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, partial

I have the following table

```
<table id="rating">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Photo Ratings</th>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Average Rating</td>
        <td><%= msg.average_rating %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Your Rating</td>
        <td><%= current_user_rating %></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Which works fine if I have it in a view, but when I put it in a partial `_rating.html.erb` I get

`undefined local variable or method 'msg' for #<#<Class:0x000003463da1570>:0x003463d9f388>`

I am linking to the partial via `<%= render :partial => "rating" %>`, what must I add to the partial link so that I dont get the error? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the `msg` variable to the locals of the partial template.

```
<%= render :partial => "rating", :locals => { :msg => msg } %>
```

Comment: @colbern don't forget `current_user_rating` :)

Comment: @rubish if that one isn't a helper method :)