# devise rails - error messages in different view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm trying to show my errors (both flash and devise) in one of my layout files (_header.html.erb):

```
<div id="alerts">
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
<% end %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
</div>
```

but I'm getting an error: undefined local variable or method `resource', because the error message is no longer in the devise form. I tried the method suggested here: http://pupeno.com/2010/08/29/show-a-devise-log-in-form-in-another-page/ by pasting that code into the application_controller.rb file. No luck. Ideas?

oh. I forgot to mention... The pages work without error, but my tests are failing... Here's a failing test:

```
it 'succeeds with a valid email and password' do
  user = Factory.create(:user)

  visit sign_in_path
  fill_in 'user_email', :with => user.email
  fill_in 'user_password', :with => user.password
  click_button 'Sign in'
  page.should have_content("hi #{user.username}")
end
```

This is Rails3, fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out the code needed to be in the application_helper instead of the controller, but the code at pupeno.com works!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting errors like this and solved using :partial and :locals when using the render method:

```
<%= render :partial => 'header', :locals => { :flash => flash } %>
```

See [Rails 3: "undefined local variable or method" if I put content in a partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128123/rails-3-undefined-local-variable-or-method-if-i-put-content-in-a-partial)